Formatting Input Field onChange While Retaining Value
I am trying to format the value of an input field onChange. I am wanting to add a space after every 4th character (i.e. a credit card number). It is currently clearing the text field after the 5th character (which is technically the space).
This is what I have done and how to reproduce the above.
const [creditCardNumber, setCreditCardNumber] = useState<string>('');
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

   let creditNum = e.target.value;
   let creditNumSpaced = creditNum.match(/.{1,4}/g);
   setCreditCardNumber(creditNumSpaced?.join(' ') ?? '');
};


<Input type='number' onChange={e => handleChange(e)} value={creditCardNumber}


It looks like you're trying to format a credit card number input field by adding a space after every 4th character. However, the current implementation clears the text field after the 5th character due to the space being added.
Try this code insted:
const [creditCardNumber, setCreditCardNumber] = useState<string>('');
 const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let creditNum = e.target.value;
    let creditNumWithoutSpaces = creditNum.replace(/\s/g, ''); // Remove spaces
    let creditNumSpaced = creditNumWithoutSpaces.match(/.{1,4}/g);
    setCreditCardNumber(creditNumSpaced?.join(' ') ?? '');
  };


<Input type='number' onChange={e => handleChange(e)} value={creditCardNumber}

